# parsing multi sections of a text file C#

Tags: c#, parsing, text

First let me start by thanking you all for being part of this site, I have already gained so much helpful information from it. including some basic parsing of text files in to Arrays, but i now want to go a step further.

I have a text file that looks some thing like this

```
Start Section 1 - foods

apple  
bannana  
pear   
pineapple  
orange  

end section 1

Start section 2 - animals

dog  
cat  
horse  
cow  

end section 2
```

what I want to do is using a single read of the file copy the data from section 1 in to an array called "foods" and section 2 in to and array called "animals"

now I can get it to work by using a new loop for each section, closing and reopening the file each time, looping till I find the section I want and creating the array.

But I was thinking there must be a way to read each section in to a separate array in one go saving time.

so my current code is

```
List<string> typel = new List<string>();  

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("types.txt")) // opens file using streamreader
        {

            string line; // reads line by line in to varible "line"
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) // loops untill it reaches an empty line
            {
                typel.Add(line); // adds the line to the list varible "typel"
                               }

        }

        Console.WriteLine(typel[1]);  // test to see if list is beeing incremented
        string[] type = typel.ToArray(); //converts the list to a true array 
        Console.WriteLine(type.Length); // returns the number of elements of the array created.
```

which is for a simple text file with no sections just list of values, using list seemed a good way to deal with unknown lengths of arrays.

I was also wondering how to deal with the first value.

for example if i do

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != Start Section 1 - foods)  
{  
}  
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != end Section 1)   
{  
foods.Add(line);  
}  
...  
....
```

I end up with the "start Section 1 - foods" as one of the array elements. I can remove it with code but is there an easy way to avoid this so only the list items get populated?

Cheers and once again thanks for all the help. Its great to be getting back in to programming after many many years.

Aaron

Comment: Why convert to 'real array' ? Avoid arrays when you can. List<> is better.

Comment: List<T> is just an generic implementation of ArrayList you know.

Comment: from the old days arrays were the things I am happy with (ish) :)   Also I found Array.IndexOf(foods, apple) which for what I am doing will be very helpfull. Basically this will be a c# implementation of the perl page www.devilwah.cpm\switch.shtml I wrote a while back, but much neater and far more flexible.

Comment: Arrays are so 20th century. List<T> has IndexOf too, and Add/Insert/Remove for bonus.

Comment: but "list" sounds so simple and basic (like i am going shopping), array has much nicer ring to it ;)  But I will look in to them maybe a bit more, I got the impression from my research that arrays are more efficent code?? And then there are Dictionary's as well, still yet to find a use for them. (looking at your code below now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for pointers for start and end. This is where you start putting things into arrays, lists, etc.

Here is a stab at making it very flexible:

```
class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> _arrayLists = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = "c:\\logs\\arrays.txt";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        string line;
        string category = "";

        while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
        {
            if (line.ToLower().Contains("start"))
            {
                string[] splitHeader = line.Split("-".ToCharArray());
                category = splitHeader[1].Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!_arrayLists.ContainsKey(category))
                {
                    List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
                    _arrayLists.Add(category, stringList);
                }

                if((!line.ToLower().Contains("end")&&(line.Trim().Length > 0)))
                {
                    _arrayLists[category].Add(line.Trim());
                }
            }
        }

        //testing
        foreach(var keyValue in _arrayLists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Category: {0}",keyValue.Key);
            foreach(var value in keyValue.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}".PadLeft(5, ' '), value);
            }
        }


        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok two interesting its of code to have a look through cheers guys.

Answer (score 5):

Reading the lines is not the issue, see `System.IO.ReadAllLines(fileName)` and its siblings.

What you need is a (very simple) interpreter:

```
// totally untested
Dictionary<string, List<string>> sections = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
List<string> section = null;

foreach(string line in GetLines())
{
   if (IsSectionStart(line))
   {
      string name = GetSectionName(line);
      section = new List<string>();
      sections.Add(name, section);
   }
   else if (IsSectionEnd(line))
   {          
      section = null;  // invite exception when we're lost
   }
   else
   {
      section.Add(line);
   }
}


...
List<string> foods = sections ["foods"];
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, if you don't want to parse the text file yourself, you could always use a quick and dirty regular expression if you're comfortable with them:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"Start Section \d+ - (?<section>\w+)\r\n(?<list>[\w\s]+)End Section", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText("types.txt")))
{
    string section = match.Groups["section"].Value;
    string[] items = match.Groups["list"].Value.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    data.Add(section, new List<string>(items));
}

// data["animals"] now contains a list of "dog", "cat", "horse", and "cow"
```

In response to the comment:

> but "list" sounds so simple and basic
>   (like i am going shopping), array has
>   much nicer ring to it ;) But I will
>   look in to them maybe a bit more, I
>   got the impression from my research
>   that arrays are more efficent code?

It's not about whether a list vs. array is "basic" or "has a nicer ring", it's about the purpose of the code. In your case, you're iterating a file line-by-line and adding items to a collection of an unknown size beforehand - which is one problem a list was designed to solve. Of course you could peek through the file and determine the exact size, but is doing that worth the extra "efficiency" you get from using an array, and is iterating the file twice going to take longer than using a list in the first place? You don't know unless you profile your code and conclude that specific portion is a bottleneck... which I'll say, will almost never be the case.

Comment: OK sorry I think you miseed the sarcasam in my tone.

Comment: Dam Internetfroze, OK sorry I think you miseed the sarcasam in my tone. I actuly started by using a fixed lenth array (had not ome across list), then found out about list so gave that a go, and then was playing about converting lists to arrays. At the moemnt this is all playing around seeing what things you can do these days. the finaly disecisions on what I will use will vary depending on what I am going to sue the arrays/lists for. I have a feeling it might end up a mixture. Still need to read up and find out lots more :)

Answer (score 0):

Uhmmm, like this?

```
//converting it to array called allLines, elements/index per line
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines("types.txt").ToArray();

//getting the index of allLines that contains "Start Section 1" and "end section 1" 
int[] getIndexes = new int[] { Array.FindIndex(allLines, start => start.Contains("Start Section 1")), Array.FindIndex(allLines, start => start.Contains("end section 1")) };

//create list to get indexes of the list(apple,banana, pear, etc...)
List<int> indexOfList = new List<int>();

//get index of the list(apple,banana, pear,etc...)
for (int i = getIndexes[0]; i < getIndexes[1]; i++)
{
    indexOfList.Add(i);
}

//remove the index of the element or line "Start Section 1"
indexOfList.RemoveAt(0);
//final list
string[] foodList = new string[]{ allLines[indexOfList[0]], allLines[indexOfList[1]], and so on...};
```

Then you can call them or edit then save.

```
//call them
Console.Writeline(foodList[0] + "\n" + foodList[1] + ...)

//edit the list
allLines[indexOfList[0]] = "chicken"; //from apple to chicken
allLines[indexOfList[1]] = "egg"; //from banana to egg
//save lines
File.WriteAllLines("types.txt", allLines);
```